# Add number 1 to every element in list

Tags: python

I have a list with 3 variables, number, atom and weight. I need to for every object in the list add 1 to number. That way I get the right atomic number for every atom in the list. I have some trouble doing this.
The code so far: Disclaimer atomer2.txt is the file I read all the information about the elements in from. It looks like this:

```
Ac 227.0
Ag 107.868
Al 26.98154
...
```

```
class Periodic:
    def __init__(self, number, weight, atom):
        self.number = number
        self.atom = atom
        self.weight = weight

    def __str__(self):
        return self.atom + " " + str(self.weight)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.number) + " " + self.atom + " " + str(self.weight)


def create_atom_list():
    atom_file = open('atomer2.txt', 'r')
    atom_list = []
    number = 1
    for line in atom_fil:
        data = line
        weight = float(data.split()[1])
        atom = data.split()[0]
        new_atom = Periodic(number, weight, atom)
        atom_lista.append(new_atom)
    atom_lista.sort(key=lambda x: x.weight)
    atom_fil.close()
    for i in atom_list:
        number += 1
    print(atom_lista)
    return atom_lista
create_atom_list

Now the list looks like this: [1 H 1.0079, 1 He 4.0026, 1 Li 6.941, 1 Be 9.01218, ...]
I have tried writing the for loop
```

for i in atom_list:
number += 1

```
but I seem to be missing something. Any idea on how I can fix it.
```

Comment: There are quite a few typos in your code. Maybe you need to first get rid of those.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop `for i in atom_list` don't have effect. `number` needs to be incremented inside loop `for line in atom_file:`

And you have many errors in code.

I will rewrite it to more readable, reusable and pythonic code:

```py
class Periodic:
    def __init__(self, number, atom, weight):
        self.number = number
        self.atom = atom
        self.weight = float(weight)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.atom} {self.weight}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.number} {self.atom} {self.weight}"

def create_atom_list():
    atom_list = []
    number = 0
    with open('atomer2.txt', 'r') as atom_file:
        for line in atom_file:
            number += 1
            atom, weight = line.split()
            new_atom = Periodic(number, atom, weight)
            atom_list.append(new_atom)
    atom_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.weight)
    return atom_list

atoms = create_atom_list()
print(atoms)
```

or shorter

```py
with open('atomer2.txt', 'r') as f:
    atom_list = sorted([Periodic(i+1, *line.split()) for i, line in enumerate(f)], key=lambda x: x.weight)
```

Comment: The good ol' python one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_atom_list():
    atom_file = open('atomer2.txt', 'r')
    atom_lista = []
    number = 1
    for line in atom_fil:
        data = line
        weight = float(data.split()[1])
        atom = data.split()[0]
        new_atom = Periodic(number, weight, atom)
        atom_lista.append(new_atom)
    atom_lista.sort(key=lambda x: x.weight)
    atom_fil.close()
    for i in range(len(atom_list)):
        atom_lista[i].number = i+1
    print(atom_lista)
    return atom_lista
```

Comment: When I try your suggestion the number becomes the number where every element in the file is positioned and not in the list. So hydrogen gets the atomic number 37 since its on row 37 in the file I read in to the program.

Comment: yes you are correct, my mistake. How about now? Here we update the atom numbers in the second for loop. (The answer has been updated)